# AttributeError: module 'setuptools._distutils' has no attribute 'version'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, distutils

I was trying to train a model using tensorboard.
While executing, I got this error:

```
$ python train.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 6, in <module>
    from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter  
  File "C:\Users\91960\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    LooseVersion = distutils.version.LooseVersion 

AttributeError: module 'setuptools._distutils' has no attribute 'version'.
```

I'm using python 3.8.9 64-bit & tensorflow with distutils already installed which is required by tensorboard.

Why is this happening?

Comment: do `pip install fairseq
pip install setuptools==59.5.0` worked for me

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This command did the trick for me:

`python3 -m pip install setuptools==59.5.0`

pip successfully installed this version:

`Successfully installed setuptools-60.1.0` instead of `setuptools-60.2.0`

Answer (score 74):

This is a known bug which has been patched: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/69904

You can either use the nightly-release of PyTorch, or otherwise downgrade setup tools to `setuptools` version `59.5.0`:

`pip install setuptools==59.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

I personally needed to run this:

```
pip install fairseq
pip install setuptools==59.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing to use older versions of PyTorch, such as NVidia Jetson TX2 users building PyTorch 1.10.0 for newer python version, it is simpler to add the missing import to the setup.py file:

```
import distutils.version
```

... This should be added after the future import.  The same trick should work for other projects, as this ensures that distutils.version is available, where it was previous automatically imported by setuptools.